# Java 8 Map.Entry comparator

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, java-8, comparator

I've been trying to make **Map.Entry Comparator** in Java8 using lambda expressions and have found a very strange behaviour.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>();

map.put(1, "Hello");
map.put(3, "zzzz");
map.put(2, "aaaa");
map.put(5, "AAAAA");
map.put(4, "aaaa");

Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> com = Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue);
com = com.reversed();

Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> com2 = Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue).reversed();
```

**com** works just fine, but **com2** contains a misstake "*cannot resolve method getValue*". And I really don't know why? Any suggestions?

P.S. Is there any way to avoid typing **Map.Entry** with **Integer, String**? Any shorter way?

Comment: This seems to be a limitation of how the Java compiler infers the generic parameters and the return type of a lambda, so there probably isn't much you can do here. You can wait for the next version of the compiler, which may be smarter. :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since Java-8 there's a standalone method [`Entry.comparingByValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue--) which can be used instead:

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> com2 = 
        Map.Entry.<Integer, String>comparingByValue().reversed();
```

An alternative way to do the same is to pass the parameter:

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> com2 = 
        Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

This way type arguments are unnecessary.

Answer (score 14):

Currently you're specifying the raw type when you specify the method reference - in the first case generic type inference with the assignment tells the compiler what you mean, but that doesn't work for the target of a method call. You can specify the generic type for the method reference though:

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> com2 = 
    Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<Integer,String>::getValue).reversed();
```

(I realize that's *increasing* the number of times you need `Map.Entry<Integer, String>` in your code, but unfortunately that's hard to avoid here.)

Comment: Thanks, than definetly worked! Though Intellij shows the same warning. But can I avoid typing this much Map.Entry<Integer,String>?

Comment: @ДмитрийКиселев: You *may* be able to get away with it by writing your own utility methods that call `reverse`, but they'd be ugly in other ways...